# Linux Bridge over ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, network-interface

I have eth0 (Dhcp running). I want to create bridge over eth0 without losing N/w on eth0.

I have tried following

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth1
```

Is it possible to create Bridge (br0 here) without losing n/w on interface (eth0)

Comment: Creating a bridge with (only) eth1 should not affect eth0. Are you sure you did what you claim?

Comment: you can create bridge b/w any interfaces but what are you trying to achieve with only one interface in bridge

Comment: @jonasWielicki I want to use eth1 (on which dhcp is running) to create bridge.

Comment: @vkumar I want to use bridge ( only on eth1) to create VM n/w.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a route with `iptables` :

`su -
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 0):

### How to Setup Linux Bridge

The standard configuration should consist of:

- Create the bridge interface.

  `root@ubuntu-1:~ # brctl addbr br0`
- Add existing interfaces to the bridge.

  `root@ubuntu-1:~ # brctl addif br0 eth0
   root@ubuntu-1:~ # brctl addif br0 eth1`
- Zero IP the interfaces.

  `root@ubuntu-1:~ # ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
  root@ubuntu-1:~ # ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0`
- Put up the bridge.

  `root@ubuntu-1:~ # ifconfig br0 up`

***Optionally you can configure the virtual interface br0 to take part in your network. To behaves like one interface (i.e a normal network card).***

`root@ubuntu-1:~ # ifconfig br0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

To learn visit [How to Setup bridge network for KVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952531/setting-up-bridged-networks-for-kvm/952573#952573)